# In what form do lord Brahma,Vishnu and lord Shiva exist? What is the only source of their infinite power!? What is their life like & what do they eat?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, spirituality, knowledge

So, only lord Brahma lord Vishnu and lord Shiva corresponds to this entire existence and **what are they and what are we!?**

1. How they were created and what energy they surpass through!?
2. Is there any chances or redirections to any human species likely to
   exist such as them?
3. How do I calm and understand myself if I believe all these supreme
   power are vested only to them and not human afterall these dreams
   and dimensions I travel through each nights and all these images
   that are formed in my head?
4. Is it possible to summon the source of power they have and how I
   become one like Vishnu brahma and the lord Shiva--before dying
   recklessly here like general human beings?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to HSE! Please take a tour of this site https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour and get familiar :) Also, Please modify your question as it includes multiple questions in a single one and also it's a bit confusing i.e., against forum rules.. so your question might get closed.

Comment: What is Agni Dev? Vayu Dev? Surya Dev?  - Fire, Air, sun. Each corresponds to personified form of a thing. Similarly, Brahma, Vishnu and Maheshvara correspond to birth, sustainance and death.